# Destroying Base classes based on derived class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using two classes one is Base class `vehicle` and other one derived class `Car`. All method and properties of base class accessing in multiple derived classes.Instance created only for child class `Car` etc.

here i have created sample example in [github](https://github.com/CP-Ram/AngularMemoryLeaksTestApp/tree/master),[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-initializedestroy-ayisvw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.ts)(for me heap snapshot not working)

**Base class**:

```
export class Vehicle implements OnDestroy{
}
```

**Derived class**:

```
export class Car extends Vehicle {
}
```

**form component**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Car } from '../utils/Car';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form',
  templateUrl: './form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form.component.css']
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  utilInstance;
  isInitialization
  constructor(public appService:AppService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.utilInstance=new Car(this.appService);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log('form destroy')

   this.utilInstance=null;
  }

}
```

After destroying Car class,Taken chrome browser dev-tool heap [image: snapshot] but Vehicle class still present in memory even after deleted existing snapshot and than refreshed application tab and again taken heap snapshot.

How to destroy base class Vehicle?

Please give me suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: Your screenshot does not show the retainer for the object.

Comment: Try without the `console.log(this.utilInstance)` - the console might well be the object holding onto your instance. Also, why do your `Car` and `Vehicle` classes have `ngOnDestroy()` methods, they're not angular components?

Comment: @Bergi i have removed console.log(this.utilInstance) and ngOnDestroy()..now what need to do to remove Vehicle instance?Any other way to use Vehicle in such a way so that it will get remove on child instance remove?

Comment: `this.utilInstance=null` is just fine.